# How to restrict traffic to AWS loadbalancer only from browsers

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, aws-application-load-balancer

How to restrict traffic to AWS Application loadbalancer only from browsers and prevent traffic from postman, curl, wget, headless browsers ..

Comment: That is simply impossible. Anything can pretend to be / actually become a browser by sending the right headers. This is unrelated to AWS or load balancers.

Comment: I don't want to use WAF, if there is a simpler solution present in the AWS load balancer. https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/waf-block-http-requests-no-user-agent

Comment: A WAF does not prevent curl or postman or wget because it can't. I repeat: this is impossible and unrelated to AWS. If postman sends an origin and user agent header you cannot distinguish it from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

As @luk2302 notes, as a general statement this is impossible. Bytes on the wire are bytes on the wire. There is no way to know what program generated them, and "pretend to be a browser" is an extremely common setting in most tools because it's necessary for testing.

There are some ways to try to interrogate the client or the human user, either through JavaScript or "CAPTCHA puzzles," and that's the tool you would use here. They are always going to be a bit wonky and imprecise because a tool can always mimic a browser (it's just bytes on the wire and browsers are just tools themselves), and the range of "puzzles that users can and are willing to solve easily but computers can't" is shrinking every year.

For AWS, the best available answer is [WAF client application integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-application-integration.html). It doesn't completely address this issue, but it does try. You note in the comments that you don't want to use WAF. I'm not certain what simpler solution you're picturing, but the answer is WAF. If there were some automatic switch you could throw and absolutely know that the connection was with a human interacting with a browser, we wouldn't use CAPTCHAs all over the place.